# Replication of databases with specific prefix on master

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication

There are [options to dynamically set variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-replication-variables/) on replication slaves, like `replicate_wild_do_table` and `replicate_wild_ignore_table`.
But, are there any options for replication master to dynamically set database names which begin with same prefix, and not repeating:

> replicate-do-db=prefix_db1
>
> replicate-do-db=prefix_other_db
>
> replicate-do-db=prefix_third_database
>
> ...

in `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically, no.

You could, however, write a `SELECT` against `information_schema.TABLES` to create the `replicate-do-db` list for subsequent manual (or programmatic) placement into the config file.

Are you really adding more databases frequently?

Would it be better to, instead, do `replicate-ignore-db` on the rest of the dbs?

Also, consider using `binlog-...` so that the filtering is done sooner (on the Master instead of on the Slave).  (Yes, there are valid reasons to delay the filtering until the Slave.)